# get_page_template_slug returns incorrect path

Tags: php, theme-development, page-template

I'm currently experiencing a very strange issue which I can't find any reason to it.

I have a theme which is working fine on all servers.
Now, I have one client who is having issues with it.  The problem is that the function get_page_template_slug() returns the theme folder name.

Ex: theme/template-home.php

It should be just template-home.php without the theme folder name.  How can this be?

Hope someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked what the function you called does and it just retrieves the `_wp_page_template` value from the `wp_postmeta` table of WordPress. So probably the structure of your theme is not right, some rewrites are active, or something else (e.g. plug-in) altered this database table.

You could check that the theme root directory is indeed the directory which you think it is.

Other things that could be happening are:

> The filename of a Page's assigned custom template is stored as the
>   value of a Custom Field with a key named '_wp_page_template' (in the
>   wp_postmeta database table). If the template is stored in a Theme's
>   subdirectory (or a Parent Theme's subdirectory of a Child Theme), the
>   value of the wp_postmeta is both the folder and file names

Which I got from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug